# How to use reference to another table in aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, cross-apply

I have following easy-to-explain task: we have a table, and we should calculate total count of rows grouped by columns. Column number is fixed so we write:

```
SELECT  [GroupId] = cr.[GroupId], 
        [OnCreateCount] =  SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [NewCount] = SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [CreatedCount] = SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 1 AND THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [ReviewCount] = SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [RejectedCount] = SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [TotalCount] = COUNT(*)
FROM [FK].[CertificateRequest] cr
GROUP BY cr.[GroupId]
```

Here `OnCreateCount` and `CreatedCount` are the same, but it's wrong. `CreatedCount` is number of rows with status 1 which are referenced from table `[Certificate]`. `OnCreate` is number of rows with status 1 which are **not** referenced from table `[Certificate]`

Here is how I solved it:

```
SELECT  [GroupId] = cr.[GroupId], 
        [OnCreateCount] =  SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 1 AND c.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [NewCount] = SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [CreatedCount] = SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 1 AND c.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [ReviewCount] = SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [RejectedCount] = SUM(CASE WHEN cr.StatusOfRequest = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [TotalCount] = COUNT(*)

FROM [FK].[CertificateRequest] cr
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM [FK].[Certificate] c
  WHERE c.CertificateRequestID = cr.ID
) c
GROUP BY cr.[GroupId]
```

But I really don't like `OUTER APPLY` here which is used just to determine whenever there is any row in referenced table.

What is the easiest way to get required result?

Answer (score 0):

The `OUTER APPLY` is probably not too bad, but if you did want to replace it with something else here is another option:

```
With cte As (
    Select GroupId,
        StatusOfRequest,
        HasCertificate = iif(Exists (Select 1 
                                       From FK.Certificate As c
                                       Where c.CertificateRequestID = cr.ID), 1, 0)
      From FK.CertificateRequest As cr)
Select GroupID,
    OnCreateCount = SUM(CASE WHEN StatusOfRequest = 1 AND HasCertificate = 0 THEN 1 END),
    ...
    NewCount = SUM(CASE WHEN StatusOfRequest = 1 AND HasCertificate = 1 THEN 1 END),
    ...
  From cte
  Group By GroupID;
```

This assumes you have a version of SQL Server which supports `iif` and common table expressions. If not, easy to translate to CASE and subquery respectively.

Comment: I have a suspicion that `OUTER APPLY` may not scale well because it may force a nested loop join, where this example seems to use other joins when the row count increases.